# RoR Couldn't find Topic without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am a newbie RoR developer. I am stuck in one problem. I am trying to make a application with users who can create a topic and others can post their comments under the topic..The topics are created by user and listed on the main page as a list.  I am almost done with the topics. But when i click them to see the posts, I get  Couldn't find Topic without an ID error.

I guess that my mistake is topics has two indexes id and user_id. 
here is my Topic model :

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :title
  belongs_to    :user
  has_many      :posts
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
  validates :content, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  default_scope order: 'topics.created_at DESC'
end
```

And my post model

```
class Posts < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content 
  belongs_to :topic
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true
  default_scope order: 'posts.created_at DESC'
end
```

this is my topics_controller.rb:

```
class TopicsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_filter :correct_user, only: :destroy

    def show
        @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
        @posts = @topic.posts.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 20
    end
       .
       ..vs
```

and this is my config/routes.rb

```
MyPedia::Application.routes.draw do
    resources :users
    resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
    resources :topics, only: [:show, :create, :destroy]
    resources :posts
    root to: 'static_pages#home'


    match '/topicin',   to: 'topics#show'
    match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete

    match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
    match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
    match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
```

my topics show.html.erb

```
<% title @topic.title %>  
<div class ="center">
<h3><%= @topic.title %></h3>  

<% if @posts? %>  


  <% for post in @posts do %>  
    <p><strong><%= post.content %>  
  <% end %>  
<% end %>  
</div>
```

I try to find a way to solve this problem. 
thanks for helps

Comment: Can you share the URL you are using and getting this error? Is it an existing ID? Are you using the resource route, or the later matched route? Generally btw, having overlapping routes is not a great idea.

Comment: http://localhost:3000/topicin this is the adress i get the error.

Comment: Yep, you re using that route wrong. /topicin does not specify an ID, so the app cannot show a record, hence the exception.

Comment: remove  match '/topicin',   to: 'topics#show' from your routes.To access particular topic use topics/1 or topics/(id)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using GET /topic/1, that will help. The way you have set up the matched route is wrong and probably redundant. You can have a look here for more info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

Although there are restful routes for topics, in the route for topics#show there is no `:id` :

```
 match '/topicin',   to: 'topics#show'  # <===== :id is missing
```

Maybe this is causing the problems.

Answer (score 0):

just add

```
 match '/topicin/:id',   to: 'topics#show'
```

Comment: Rails provides restful routes for the topics as per @ytsejam routing file.Your answer will create a redundant routes.